# Change questions using buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter, while-loop

I am new in Python programming and I am learning how to create user interfaces. I would like to create a very basic interface which has the following flow: using a while loop, the interface shows all the questions included into a list of questions. Each time a question is presented, two button (Yes-No) appears under the question. Only when one of them is clicked, the interface will show the next questions.
I attach here the code I tried.

```
import tkinter as tk

questions=['Question 1','Question 2','Question 3','Question 4', 'Question 5']
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(300, 300)
answers=['Yes','No']
b_list = [] 

def ask():
    count=0
    while count<len(questions):
        lab=tk.Label(root,text=questions[count])
        lab.pack()
        count+=1

for i in range(2):
    b = tk.Button(root, text = answers[i],command=ask)
    b.grid(row = 0, column = i)

    b_list.append(b) 

root.mainloop()
```

Such code doesn't work at all. I guess also that I made a mistake into the while loop, asking to display all the questions, instead of one at once. Any idea to make such code working?
Thanks for your time!!

Comment: First of all the buttons wont even be displayed until the while loop has ended. So you will need to move the for loop into your while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main reasons enabling your code not to run:

1. In one script you can't write GUI with two or more geometry managers. This is not only for tkinter but also for other GUI third party library like PyQt.
2. The label should display different messages or questions in each round. So it means it's necessary for you to modify the content with **StringVar**. It behaved as a variable of string. You can learn more [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

I don't have a clear idea of why you wanna store button and the place where you save the result made by users.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

questions = ['Question 1', 'Question 2',
             'Question 3', 'Question 4', 'Question 5']
answers = ['Yes', 'No']


root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(300, 300)


def ask():
    if questions:
        lab_text.set(questions.pop(0))

for index, answer in enumerate(answers):
    lab_text = tk.StringVar()
    lab = tk.Label(root, textvariable=lab_text)
    lab.grid(row=0, column=0)
    b = tk.Button(root, text=answer, command=ask)
    b.grid(row=1, column=index)

#initialize label
ask()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done in an object orientated manner which may hold up better for future proofing.

Please see my commented version of the script below for an explanation and example:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.array = ["Question1", "Question2", "Question3", "Question4", "Question5"] #list containing questions
        self.answer = [] #empty list for storing answers
        self.question = Label(self.root, text=self.array[len(self.answer)]) #creates a text label using the element in the 0th position of the question list
        self.yes = Button(self.root, text="Yes", command=self.yescmd) #creates button which calls yescmd
        self.no = Button(self.root, text="No", command=self.nocmd) #creates button which calles nocmd
        self.question.pack()
        self.yes.pack()
        self.no.pack()
    def yescmd(self):
        self.answer.append("yes") #adds yes to the answer list
        self.command() #calls command
    def nocmd(self):
        self.answer.append("no") #adds no to the answer list
        self.command() #calls command
    def command(self):
        if len(self.answer) == len(self.array): #checks if number of answers equals number of questions
            self.root.destroy() #destroys window
            print(self.answer) #prints answers
        else:
            self.question.configure(text=self.array[len(self.answer)]) #updates the text value of the question label to be the next question
root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is essentially only different in the sense that we're just configuring the `label` to show the next element in the questions `list` rather than destroying it or popping the `list`.